После решения задачи Java оставили такой комментарий - "оба метода должны возвращать поле " Что это значит?
public enum Day {
    MONDAY("Понедельник"),
    TUESDAY("Вторник"),
    WEDNESDAY("Среда"),
    THURSDAY("Четверг"),
    FRIDAY("Пятница"),
    SATURDAY("Суббота"),
    SUNDAY("Воскресенье");

    private final String rusName;

    Day(String rusName) {
        this.rusName = rusName;
    }

    public boolean isWeekend() {
        return this == SATURDAY || this == SUNDAY;
    }

    public String getRusName() {
        return this.rusName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Day day : Day.values()) {
            System.out.println(day.name() + " (" + day.getRusName() + "): " 
                + (day.isWeekend() ? "Это выходной." : "Это не выходной."));
        }
    }
}


Наверное следует прояснить этот момент у автора/ов комментария

Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?

Как и написали уже, ему не понравилось, что ты возвращаешь сравнение и это нигде не хранится, наверное хотели что-то такое:
public enum Day {
    MONDAY("Понедельник", false),
    TUESDAY("Вторник", false),
    WEDNESDAY("Среда", false),
    THURSDAY("Четверг", false),
    FRIDAY("Пятница", false),
    SATURDAY("Суббота", true),
    SUNDAY("Воскресенье", true);

    private final String rusName;
    private boolean isWeekend;

    Day(String rusName, boolean b) {
        this.rusName = rusName;
        this.isWeekend  = b;
    }

    public String getRusName() {
        return this.rusName;
    }
    
    public boolean getIsWeekend() {
        return this.isWeekend;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Day day : Day.values()) {
            System.out.println(day.name() + " (" + day.getRusName() + "):  isWeekend - " + day.getIsWeekend());
             System.out.println();
        }
        
    }
}

Немного глупо и непонятно зачем, так что можете не обращать внимания на это....

Вероятно, автор комментария хотел избежать "логики" в геттере и постоянных вычислений при вызове этого метода.  По поводу кода в ответе пара соображений: 1) название геттера для булевского поля лучше оставить isWeekend() как более соответствующее конвенции об именовании; 2) можно реализовать два конструктора, чтобы для будних дней вызывался вариант с именем: public Day(String name) {this(name, false);}-> MONDAY("Понедельник"),... SUNDAY("Воскресенье", true);

А почему isWeekend не final?

@Qwertiy А разве у enum не все методы final?

@talexmovedtoCodidact, я не джавист, чтобы такое знать. Но я вижу два одинаковых по сути поля - у одного написано, а у второго - нет - вот и спросил, почему так.

@Qwertiy Я про методы подумал. На полях надо явный final.

@talexmovedtoCodidact, кастомные методы в enum вполне могут быть абстрактные/не-финальные и переопределяться для соответствующих констант.  Ключевые методы name(), ordinal() и некоторые методы из класса Object (equals, hashCode, clone, finalize) и метод сравнения compareTo также финальные.

Добавить в конструктор второй параметр и поле для него, а из метода возвращать значение этого поля. Впрочем, я не понимаю, зачем.
